# Curly brackets and set of list in python

Tags: python, set

I was working with the date structure of set implemented in python.
I can define a set as:
`set_1 = set([1, 2])`
and also as `set_2 = {1, 2}`.
if I run `set_1 == set_2` it evaluate to `True` but if I run `set_1 is set_2` it evaluate to `False`.
So what are the difference between this two implementations?

Comment: thanks, Yes it was a duplication but I did not notice it since I was thinking at `is` as an equivalent version of  javascript `===`.

Answer (score 0):

`is` is an identity operator where as `==` checks for only values. It's already answered, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) question.

Comment: thanks, Yes it was a duplication but I did not notice it since I was thinking at `is` as an equivalent version of  javascript `===`.